# Try to get highest number without using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to get the highest number, but I don't want to use LINQ.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  int defineArray = 0;
  int numberTobefilled = 0;

  Console.WriteLine("how large do you want the array");
  defineArray = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  int[] arrAydefined = new int[defineArray]; // Array size in place
  Random rnd = new Random(); //  set to random////add some seed

  for (int i = 0; i < arrAydefined.Length; i++) {
    numberTobefilled = rnd.Next(defineArray);
    Console.WriteLine(" [{0}] ", numberTobefilled);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we mostly help people debug a specific error on their code. Please add more information about the error you are getting in your program. If you are not sure what you should ask for, don't hesitate to look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: I'm not really sure what it is you are asking here. I don't see where you fill the array anywhere on the code you've provided.

Comment: Random rnd = new Random(); and numberTobefilled = rnd.Next(defineArray);
Fills the array.  But the question is  how I get the highest/larger number